# multiple http redirect php

Tags: php, redirect

I have a link hitting on which the user is redirected to another url say "A".

```
header('Location: '.$urlA.'&timestamp='.$epochtimestamp);
    exit;
```

I now have a need to do a http redirect to another page, but not actually redirecting user to that page, because that's more of a page which records some kind of stat, but gives no user interface to it, and then redirect to my original url A

```
//Redirect to impression page
header('Location: '.$urlB.'&timestamp='.$epochtimestamp);
//Redirect to clicks page
header('Location: '.$urlA.'&timestamp='.$epochtimestamp);
    exit;
```

is this possible?

Comment: Is `$urlB` a page with PHP code you are in control of, and could therefore refactor into an include rather than an HTTP hit?  Must the user's client browser visit `$urlB` or could you issue a `curl` or `file_get_contents()` request against it from your server?

Comment: So we need more information about what `$urlB` is - whether it is local to your site or external, and what it needs from a client requesting it.

Comment: no its not local, its a client's page, thus not in my control

Comment: @BrijRajSingh Does the page expect that the end user's browser hits it (with the client browser's remote IP, user agent, etc...) or does the URL just need to be pinged by _something_?  If it just needs to be pinged, issue a curl request to it from PHP. If it needs the end user's real browser, you can't do it.

Comment: thanks @MichaelBerkowski urlA and B both need to be hit by the real browser, is it possible to create a CURL request which emulates the headers of an incoming http request